# TrackTo Constraint

Tags: constraints

[image]

I tracked the eyes of my character to a separate bone and parented the bone to the head bone. I want to be able to use that bone to control the rotation of my character. When I rotate the head bone (which is the parent) the eyes popped out of the body. How can I fixed this please?

Comment: Make the head bone parent of the eye bones.

Comment: FFeller, what you see in the picture is what happened when I made the head bone parent of the eyes' bone. The eyes doesn't original have bones except for the one I intended using to control the eyes which can be seen opposite the eyes. When I applied weight paint to my mesh there was no eyes, I modelled the eyes after and positioned it so it doesn't have a bone.

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Moonboots I have uploaded the .blend file using the link you sent to me. Can you see it?